# travis-ci — Waiting for status to be reported

Tags: github, travis-ci

I pushed a new commit to my git repo, but travis-ci build isn't triggered.

[image]

It show:

> continuous-integration/travis-ci — Waiting for status to be reported

but no job is running on travis-ci. It is so strange!

Anyone has idea for this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe a wrong access token is used? (https://github.com/cla-assistant/cla-assistant/issues/77#issuecomment-149905567)

Comment: today we tried to reopen the PR, then CI can work normally, but this method doesn't work in yesterday. Cannot find the root cause.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I didn't find the root cause, this problem only happens sometimes. But if your commit contains [skip ci], the build job will never be run. Sometimes , everything is ok after reopen the PR. @Shakeel if you meet this issue, you can send email to github support team, they can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It says "Waiting for status to be reported." I believe what happened is that GitHub thinks Travis CI is running a job. But it isn't. **Try re-running and/or cancelling the jobs in both GitHub and Travis CI.** That should work.